# Was the big statue foot, with only four toes, ever explained in Lost?

Tags: lost

There were several episodes that showed the huge statue foot and ankle on the island. Was the origin of said foot ever explained?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The statue was of Tawaret, the Egyptian goddess of pregnancy and fertility. It was shown in flashbacks (in *LaFleur* and *The Incident*) before the Black Rock crashed into it in the 1800s (in *Ab Aeterno*).

[image]

Its construction is never shown, but it was revealed in a podcast that it was built by ancient Egyptians.

There's [more information on the Lost wiki](http://lostpedia.wikia.com/wiki/Statue_of_Taweret).

Comment: Tawaret was a hippo goddess, and hippos only have four toes.

Comment: I do wonder how the Ancient Egyptians found their way to the island with enough construction gear to achieve Tawaret's construction. The Egyptians had a decent Navy, but unless the island teleported directly into the Nile at some point... I dunno; this always seemed a little strange.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Ice bears were teleported between the island and other places throughout the series. Who says the Ancient Egyptians arrived by boat?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: The Dharma Initiative created the time machine by harnessing the island's EM. Who did that thousands of years ago? And how come the Egyptians happened to bring a ton of construction equipment along with them? An Egyptian construction crew and several tones of masonry stone is not a polar bear.

Answer (score 0):

As answered by Jem above and confirmed by writers, that statue was The statue was of Tawaret, the Egyptian goddess of pregnancy and fertility. Built by ancient Egyptians.

Why did they build? Simple. The island had a bad influence on pregnant women. The Egyptians were polytheistic. It's only obvious that they would build such a statue who's like the goddess of pregnancy and fertility, to protect them from such bad influence.

P.S. - No idea if the writers did that on purpose or they just put the statue right there (given it's the popular Egyptian statue) and somehow it just happens to be explainable.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. You could improve this answer by [edit]ing it to include citations of any relevant sources you know of. For example, when you say _"The island had a bad influence on pregnant women"_, where/when was that established?